# How to get localized street name from coordinates?

Tags: ios, localization, reverse-geocoding

I use CLGeocoder to get address from geographic coordinates.

```
self.geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init]; 
///

[self.geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:loc completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
      if (placemarks.count) {
             CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];

             NSString *string = ((NSString *)[[placemark addressDictionary] objectForKey:kABPersonAddressStreetKey];
     }
}]);
```

As i have understood, CLGeocoder returns the names of streets in "native" localization (if we are in Ukraine and choose Ukrainean locale - we will obtain Ukrainean-localized street names).

This code returns me string, localized for my current location (Ukrainean).
And if the locale is set to another location, it gives me English-localized name of street.
How can i force CLGeocoder to give me addresses only in specific location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately I don't know anything about `GLGeocoder`, but I've used [Google Maps API](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=57.5,12.3&sensor=true&language=uk) for that type of thing in the past, and that worked excellent IMHO.